# User matching query does not exist while using facebook login in django project

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, django-allauth

I have set up social login for facebook for my site using django all auth. I am using JS_SDK method for facebook (instead of oauth2).

On logging in, the page errors out with "User matching query does not exist".

Full error stack is here:

```
    Traceback:
File "/home/aniket/python/insight_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages /django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/aniket/python/insight_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/facebook/views.py" in login_by_token
77.                     ret = complete_social_login(request, login)
File "/home/aniket/python/insight_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/helpers.py" in complete_social_login
131.     sociallogin.lookup()
File "/home/aniket/python/insight_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/models.py" in lookup
251.             self.user = self.account.user
File "/home/aniket/python/insight_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in __get__
572.                 rel_obj = qs.get()
File "/home/aniket/python/insight_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
357.                 self.model._meta.object_name)

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /accounts/facebook/login/token/
Exception Value: User matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: There's any records on your SocialAccount table?

Comment: Thanks Danielfranca. I was able to fix it after removing corresponding records from the socialaccount table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Danielfranca. I was able to fix it after removing corresponding records from the socialaccount table.